# Openssl runtime returns encrypted string only

Tags: linux, compilation, openssl, cross-compiling, fips

I am cross compiling an updated version openssl-fips and openssl for an embedded linux platform in the same manner as we have in previous versions.  It all compiles nicely, but when introduced to the embedded platform, I get a behavior I have not seen before.  No matter what command parameters I pass to it, it simply returns an encrypted string or a checksum or some random series of numbers, as follows:

## openssl version

878ea738d2099bcfcad2d1c474bfc01cc80d831

I have asked this on the openssl mailing list but haven't received any responses yet. Also, I have dug all over the internet to get any kind of information on what is causing it. Is it due to incompatible fips module & openssl versions.  Or have I accidently set this to a fips only feature instead of one that can be toggled?

Comment: The problem statement is not clear. You should show the relevant code, your expected output and actual output. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."*

Comment: Determined that it just won't cross compile in an Ubuntu 16.04 environment.  Compiled it in an Ubuntu 14.04 environment without issue.  Have too much on my plate to dig into it any further at this time.